# physical web android client build error : com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build sample physical web android client from [here](https://github.com/google/physical-web). After importing into android studio, I am facing this error :

```
Unknown source file : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Unknown source file : com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Unknown source file : ...while parsing org/physical_web/collection/BitmapRequest$RequestCallback.class
Unknown source file : 1 error; aborting

:app:preDexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I haven't changed anything in the code, so don't know why this error. Please help.

If I change the jdk version from 1.8 to 1.7, the error changes to :

```
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/physical_web/collection/Request$RequestCallback;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Update :

Here are all my gradle files :

for `app` module :

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
    apply plugin: 'findbugs'
    apply plugin: 'pmd'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "physical_web.org.physicalweb"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 15
        versionName "0.1.856"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    if(new File("signing.properties").exists()) {
        Properties signingProperties = new Properties()
        signingProperties.load(new FileInputStream(new File('signing.properties')))

        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile new File(signingProperties['storeFile'])
                storePassword signingProperties['storePassword']
                keyAlias signingProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword signingProperties['keyPassword']
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        // We'll get to fixing the icon later
        disable 'IconLauncherShape', 'IconDensities', 'IconMissingDensityFolder', 'LongLogTag'
        // Travis requires an older api at the moment
        disable 'OldTargetApi'
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(project(':libs')) {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

    compile 'com.android.volley:volley@aar'
    compile 'org.uribeacon:uribeacon-library-release@aar'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}

task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
    configProperties.checkstyleSuppressionsPath = new File(rootDir, "app/config/checkstyle/suppressions.xml").absolutePath
    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'
    classpath = files()
}

task findbugs(type: FindBugs, dependsOn: assembleDebug) {
    ignoreFailures = false
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "high"
    classes = files("${project.rootDir}/app/build/intermediates/classes")
    excludeFilter = file("${project.rootDir}/app/config/findbugs/exclude-filter.xml")

    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'

    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
        xml {
            destination "$project.buildDir/reports/findbugs/findbugs.xml"
        }
        html {
            destination "$project.buildDir/reports/findbugs/findbugs.html"
        }
    }

    classpath = files()
}

task pmd(type: Pmd, dependsOn: assembleDebug) {
    ignoreFailures = false
    ruleSetFiles = files("${project.rootDir}/app/config/pmd/pmd-ruleset.xml")
    ruleSets = []

    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'

    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
        xml {
            destination "$project.buildDir/reports/pmd/pmd.xml"
        }
        html {
            destination "$project.buildDir/reports/pmd/pmd.html"
        }
    }
}

check.dependsOn 'checkstyle', 'findbugs', 'lint', 'pmd'
```

settings.gradle :

```
include ':app', ':libs'

project(':libs').projectDir = new File('../../java/libs')
```

for 'libs' project :

```
    plugins {
    id 'checkstyle'
    id 'findbugs'
    id 'java'
    id 'pmd'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integrationTest/java')
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.json:json:20140107'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.2.3'
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

findbugsMain {
    ignoreFailures = false
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "low"
    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }
}

findbugsTest {
    ignoreFailures = false
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "low"
    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }
}

findbugs {
    reportsDir = new File(buildDir, "reports/findbugs")
    excludeFilter = new File(projectDir, "config/findbugs/exclude-filter.xml")
}

checkstyle {
    configProperties.checkstyleSuppressionsPath =
            new File(projectDir, "config/checkstyle/suppressions.xml")
}

pmdMain {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }
}

pmd {
    ignoreFailures = false
    ruleSetFiles = files(new File(projectDir, "config/pmd/pmd-ruleset.xml"))
    ruleSets = []
    reportsDir = new File(buildDir, "reports/findbugs")
}

javadoc {
    source = sourceSets.main.java
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    reports.html.destination = file("${reporting.baseDir}/${name}")
}

integrationTest.dependsOn assemble
```

Comment: plz share gradle file....!!!

Comment: @ExceptionLover : added all my gradle files

Answer (score 1):

I Solved it after 2-3 hours.

This project needs JDK 1.7. On JDK 1.8, it gives that `Unknown source file : com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)`
.

Why I was getting the `com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/physical_web/collection/Request$RequestCallback;`
 error after changing the jdk to 1.7 is because I forgot to clean the project before running it again. So, there were multiple dex files, one that was generated with jdk 1.8 and one which was generated with jdk 1.7.